# Bash/Как убрать пробелы из строки?

Tags: bash

Есть код для определения палиндромов:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a string: " string
if [[ $(rev <<< "$string") == "$string" ]]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```

Он работает только на строках без пробелов. То есть на фразе "у дуба буду" скрипт не работает корректно.
Как можно добавить возможность игнорировать все пробелы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь утилитой [`tr`](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=1&topic=tr) с опцией `-d`, чтобы удалить все пробелы:

```bash
string="$(tr -d ' ' <<< "$string")"
```

После чего производите сравнение:

```bash
"$(rev <<< "$string")" == "$string"
```

Answer (score 3):

Баш умеет такое:

```
$ var='come get some'
$ echo $var
come get some

$ echo ${var/' '}  # удалить первый попавшийся символ ' '
comeget some

$ echo ${var//' '} # удалить все символы ' '
comegetsome
```

Можно не удалять а заменить:

```
$ echo ${var/' '/_}  # заменить первый попавшийся символ ' ' на '_'
come_get some

$ echo ${var//' '/_} # заменить все символы ' ' на '_'
come_get_some
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать стандартную обработку переменной bash:

```txt
${переменная//что меняем/на что меняем}  
____________^^________________________ -глобальная замена, одиночный слеш только первое вхождение
```

Удаляем пробелы `${string// }`
Пример:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter a string: " string
if [[ $(rev <<< "${string// }") == "${string// }" ]]; then
    echo "YES"
else
    echo "NO"
fi
```